# How composing a group of middlewares that are common

Tags: express, middleware

I know I can make use of the method `app.use` to include a middleware or I can pass middleware before my controllers

```
app
.use(middleware1)
.get('/some/path', middlewarePath1, middlewarePath2, (req, res) => {...})
```

But How composing a group of middlewares that are common?

Example

```
var composeMiddleware = compose(middlewarePath1, middlewarePath2)

app
.get('/some/path', composeMiddleware, (req, res) => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like creating a wrapper middleware

```
var composeMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('calling first middleware');
  console.log('calling second middleware');
  next();
}
```

And then use this

```
app.get('/some/path', composeMiddleware, (req, res) => {...})
```

For more info regarding custom middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html